# chai / chai-things check object array for an object with prop / value when other props are unknown

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm experimenting with chai / chai-things, the chai-things docs have this example:

```
[{ a: 'cat' }, { a: 'dog' }].should.include.something.that.deep.equals({ a: 'cat' })
```

But given something like:

```
var data = [{ a: 'cat', age: someNumber }, { a: 'dog'}];
```

That won't work, so I'm looking for something in the lines of:

```
data.should.include.something.with.property('a').that.equals('cat');
```

But I can't seem to quite phrase it right, the age would be random so I can't use deep equal, and there could be other unknown properties.

Answer (score 0):

OK after a lot of experimentation, it turns out you can do this:

```
data.should.include.something.with.property('a', 'cat');
```